# assign a function to a method of an instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3, is there a way to assign a function to a method of an instance (if I may say so)? I'm not talking about class method overriding

for example :

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a): 
        self.a=a
        self.b=0

    def set_b(self):
        pass


def fun(x):
    print(x)
    x.b=2*x.a

my=MyClass(2)
my.set_b=fun

my.set_b
print(my.b)
```

The output is 0. I would like it to be 4.
I'm not very experienced and I think I don't have the right approach. I wanted to set set_b dynamically.

**Edit**

I corrected the line :

```
my.set_b
```

to :

```
my.set_b()
```

and I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "test.py", line 20, in 
> my.set_b()
> TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Comment: Your construction is very awkward: my.set_b requires an argument (an instance of MyClass) because fun(x) requires such an argument.  So you're passing a class instance to a class method.  I don't think that's what you want to do.

Unfortunately, I am not able to tell you what a working solution would be.

Comment: You can't "assign to a method". You assign *to names/attributes*.

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `my` (instance of `MyClass`) as argument to your method `set_b()` and you will have the result you are looking for :

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a): 
        self.a=a
        self.b=0

    def set_b(self):
        pass


def fun(x):
    print(x)
    x.b=2*x.a

my=MyClass(2)
my.set_b=fun

my.set_b(my)
print(my.b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (but not by replacing the class method by a function that's defined outside the class):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a): 
        self.a=a
        self.b=0

    def set_b(self):
        self.a, self.b = fun(self.a, self.b)

def fun(a,b):
    b=2*a
    return a,b


my=MyClass(2)
my.set_b()
print(my.b)
```

Comment: Yeah. This is what I do (though it doesn't feel so nice to me):
def set_b(self):
        self.set_b=set_b(self)

def set_b(x):
    x.b=2*x.a
Thanks for your time